# Videos and/or explicit instruction on hand wrapping for boxing

Tags: boxing, wrists

Either my instructors explain the hand wrapping too quickly or I'm just too dense to understand the explanations, but I'm still (after a month!) having a hard time wrapping my hands/wrists.  I feel like I'm not doing a great job.  Part of the problem is that everyone has a different way of doing it.  Can someone point me to resources (YouTube, written explanations, etc.) of how to wrap hands for boxing?  I'd be especially interested in deviations that are designed to give extra padding to certain areas such as wrists or thumbs.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I was hoping for more answers.  Surely there are more videos out there?  I searched youtube to no avail.  I would have thought that this is a common request (various ways to put on wraps).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a good description of how to wrap your hands:

http://www.expertboxing.com/boxing-basics/how-to-box/how-to-wrap-your-hands

Comment: -1 for link-only answer

Comment: All good answers and I appreciate them all.  This video was the most clear.  After doing it many times, I think I now have it down.  FWIW, I think the key is to refuse help from the instructors who offer to wrap your hands, and go ahead and wrap them yourself (and make mistakes!).

Answer (score 0):

The club I go to has a video on YouTube and their website (http://inthiscorner.ca/2012/05/05/how-to-wrap/). It takes a bit of practice to remember, if you aren't training frequently you may want to practice wrapping for a few days in a row to fix the process in your memory.

If you are looking for extra padding you can always modify the method to suit your needs. If you have good, long wraps you should have enough material available to give you some flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the video.  I'll study it some more.  I notice this seems yet another way to do it.  The folks at my gym tend to wrap in such a way that the inner palm is open.  I'm told this is to allow for sweat and keeping the hand cool.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your wrists first, then pass it over your palm, between the index finger and thumb and then go around the thumb and between each of your fingers, like in the following video:[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kgVnNAHLLM)

You'll know you've done it right when your wrists feel solid and your hand closes into a semi-fist on its own when relaxed.